# How to remove buttons from tinyMCE in wp_editor added via AJAX

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I've created a plugin with a custom post type that uses the standard editor.  Also on the page, I've got a button that causes a jQuery dialog to pop up that also contains the tinyMCE editor created with `wp_editor`.  I would like to modify the list of buttons on the toolbar, but only for the SECOND editor (the one in the dialog box).  Here's what I've got right now:

```
class MyPlugin {
    function MyPlugin() {
        // AJAX action that instantiates the second editor
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_show_my_editor', array( &$this, 'show_my_editor' );

        // enqueue the javascript that displays the editor in a dialog
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );

        /**
         * Things I've tried to get the buttons I don't want to go away
         */
        // filter buttons directly
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array( &$this, 'mce_buttons' ), 10, 2 );
        // filter tinyMCE settings pre-init
        add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', array( &$this, 'tiny_mce_before_init' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the javascript/css that displays the editor in a dialog
     */
    function admin_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'editor_dialog_js', plugins_url( 'js/editor_dialog.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-dialog' ), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery_ui_smoothness', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a wp_editor instance via AJAX call
     */
    function show_my_editor() {
        wp_editor( '', 'myeditor', array(
            'media_buttons' => false,
            'textarea_rows' => 5,
            'teeny'         => false,
            'quicktags'     => true,
            'tinymce'       => array(
                'skin'                    => 'wp_theme',
                'plugins'                 => 'wordpress, wplink',
                // setting buttons here should work, but doesn't
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic',
                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
                'theme_advanced_buttons3' => ''
            )
        ));
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Supposed to filter out buttons I don't want
     * Possibly redundant since 'theme_advanced_buttons1' is set above
     */
    function mce_buttons( $buttons, $editor ) {
        // filter out buttons ONLY for the editor loaded via AJAX
        if ( 'myeditor' == $editor ) {
            $buttons = array_diff( $buttons, array( 'strikethrough' /* ...other buttons */ ) );
        }
        return $buttons;
    }

    /**
     * Supposed to filter out buttons I don't want
     * Possibly redundant since 'theme_advanced_buttons1' is set above
     */
    function tiny_mce_before_init( $settings, $editor ) {
        // filter out buttons ONLY for the editor loaded via AJAX
        if ( 'myeditor' == $editor ) {
            $settings[ 'theme_advanced_buttons1' ] = 'bold,italic';
        }
        return $settings;
    }
} // end MyPlugin class
```

And my `editor_dialog.js` file looks like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '#show_editor_dialog_button' ).click( function() {
        $.get( ajaxurl, { action: 'show_my_editor' } )
        .success( function( editor ) {
            $( '<div></div>' ).html( editor )
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: { 'OK': function() { $( this ).dialog( 'close' ); } },
                width: 500
            });
            tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', true, 'myeditor' );
            quicktags( { id: 'myeditor' } );
        });
    });
});
```

Here's what I've found out:

1. If I remove the `if ( 'myeditor' == $editor )` conditional then the buttons are filtered out for ALL of my editors, not just the AJAX one as I desire
2. If I use `print_r( $buttons )` or `print_r( $settings[ 'theme_advanced_buttons1` ] )` in either of my filters I can see that my filters are running, that they only run when the AJAX editor is being loaded, and that the buttons I want filtered out appear to be filtered out
3. Trying all combinations of these filters and also setting the `theme_advanced_buttons1` parameter in the AJAX callback function does NOT seem to work

So, in short, I'm flummoxed and haven't been able to think of anything else to try.  It looks like I've set the appropriate filters, but then why does the toolbar on my AJAX editor still have ALL of the standard WP tinyMCE toolbar buttons?

Comment: I also tried raising/lowering the priority on the `add_filter()` calls.  No luck.  Somehow I believe the buttons are being cached on the first initialization.  [Brett Terpstra's trick for refreshing the buttons](http://brettterpstra.com/2010/04/17/adding-a-tinymce-button/) no longer works because the `tiny_mce_version` filter has been deprecated in the latest WP release.  Think I'll head over to the WP Trac site to see if I can find out why they did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  After the first editor has loaded on a page, even if you modify the `tinymce` settings in the array passed to `wp_editor()`, those settings are NOT passed along to the `tinymce` instance that is created when the page is first loaded.

Instead you have to use javascript to modify the `tinymce` instance itself.  You can leave out the filters altogether as well as the `tinymce` element of the `wp_editor()` settings array.  Here's the updated code that works:

```
class MyPlugin {
    function MyPlugin() {
        // AJAX action that instantiates the second editor
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_show_my_editor', array( &$this, 'show_my_editor' );

        // enqueue the javascript that displays the editor in a dialog
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the javascript/css that displays the editor in a dialog
     */
    function admin_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'editor_dialog_js', plugins_url( 'js/editor_dialog.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-dialog' ), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery_ui_smoothness', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a wp_editor instance via AJAX call
     */
    function show_my_editor() {
        wp_editor( '', 'myeditor', array(
            'media_buttons' => false,
            'textarea_rows' => 5,
            'quicktags'     => true
        ));
        exit;
    }

} // end MyPlugin class
```

And then the `editor_dialog.js` file:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '#show_editor_dialog_button' ).click( function() {

        // ADD THIS LINE TO MODIFY THE BUTTONS DIRECTLY THROUGH TINYMCE
        tinymce.settings.theme_advanced_buttons1 = 'bold,italic,ppadlinkto';

        $.get( ajaxurl, { action: 'show_my_editor' } )
        .success( function( editor ) {
            $( '<div></div>' ).html( editor )
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: { 'OK': function() { $( this ).dialog( 'close' ); } },
                width: 500
            });
            tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', true, 'myeditor' );
            quicktags( { id: 'myeditor' } );
        });
    });
});
```

It's nice when the solution shortens your code that much!  Just wish there were better documentation....  :)

Comment: With recent WP/TinyMCE versions, you'd want to replace `tinymce.settings.theme_advanced_buttons1` in the code above with `tinymce.settings.toolbar1`